# Inserting hyperlink in header content (CSS) - Wordpress blog

Tags: css, header

I have inserted text after my logo using the following:

```
#header:after {
content: "Blah blah blah.  Contact us at abc@xyz.com"
}
```

How can I make the email address a clickable link (to a new email with us as the recipient), ideally using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Content created using the `content` property will not interpreted as markup,

however using the `a` element with the pseudo elemet `:after` and the property value `attr()` will result in a clickable link since a child element will be created:

```
a.example::after
    {
      content: '[' attr(href) ']'; 
      color:#ff0000; 
    }

<a class="example" href="http://www.google.com"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Does this make it possible to mix regular text, and a link, in the same content element?

Comment: The link alsways needs to stay within the `href` but you can add plain text to the css `content` as well to the `a` element and it will remain clickable, you can even add a picture using `url()` in `content`.